# How to Keep 3d game object like(Cube) in place of RawImage(UI) unity3d?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am wondering to keep my 3d gameobject in place of rawimage ,image (UI) for example i have a canvas in that i have a rawimage at vector3(0,0,0) and other at Vector3(-240,320,0) so i want my 3d cube to place at that position.

Comment: Have you considered using `ScreenToWorldPoint`?

Comment: i have already tried this ScreenToWorldPoint but not working

Comment: How exactly we should use it?

Comment: How about `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(rawimage.transform.position)`?

Comment: My image is at Vector3(-240,0,0) and Vector3(0,0,0) with Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(rawimage.transform.position) it shows (0.0, 1.0, -10.0) for both cases